# Shell script to export environment variables in make

Tags: shell, unix, makefile, ksh

I want to use a ksh script to set up some environment variables that my makefile will later use. I tried to do:

```
setup:
   . myscript
```

But it gives me errors like `[[: not found`.

Is there a way to use an external script to load environment variables for make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [change the shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Choosing-the-Shell) used in the makefile:

```
SHELL = /usr/bin/ksh # Or whatever path it's at
```

*But* it's probably a good idea to convert the script to something compatible with `/bin/sh` (ideally completely POSIX-compatible) if you want it to work smoothly on other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Beware, this will probably not work as intended: as each Makefile command is executed in its own subshell, sourcing `myscript` will modify only the local environment, not the whole Makefile's one.

example:

```
debug: setup
    @echo "*** debug"
    export | grep ENVVAR || echo "ENVVAR not found"                   #(a)

setup:
    @echo "*** setup"
    export ENVVAR=OK; export | grep ENVVAR || echo "ENVVAR not found" #(b)
    export | grep ENVVAR || echo "ENVVAR not found"                   #(c)
```

output:

```
$ make debug
*** setup
export ENVVAR=OK; export | grep ENVVAR || echo "ENVVAR not found" #(b)
export ENVVAR='OK'

export | grep ENVVAR || echo "ENVVAR not found"                   #(c)
ENVVAR not found

*** debug
export | grep ENVVAR || echo "ENVVAR not found"                   #(a)
ENVVAR not found
```

As you can see, ENVVAR is found only in command (b), but commands (a) and (b) are executed in a new, clean environment.