# Creating environment variables with a script for make

Tags: shell, unix, makefile

(Related to [Shell script to export environment variables in make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502519/shell-script-to-export-environment-variables-in-make/9502730#9502730))

I want to use a shell script to create some variables that make can later use. I thought I could just source the script:

```
target:
  . myscript
  echo ${FOO}   # FOO is exported in myscript
```

but this doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How abt using an [include directive](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/Misc/Unix-info/make/make_3.html#SEC15) instead. Put the variables defs in a separate makefile instead of a shell script.

Answer (score 0):

This will work, but not quite the way you have it.  make invokes a new shell for each line, so in the example you give, echo ${FOO} is in a new shell.  You could simply do:

```
target:
  . myscript; \
  echo $${FOO}
```

note that you need two '$' signs on the $${FOO}

Answer (score 0):

Using an [include directive](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Include) to set a [target-specific variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific) might be the closest thing to what you're asking for.